# Python script communicate via websockets to Django Channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, channel

Looking for some guidance or advice.

I have Django channels set up on my webserver that allows two users to chat between each other using redis and websockets.

**How do I setup a standalone python script, so that it can communicate and take commands via websocket messages sent by a user in Django**.

The goal is to have this standalone python script  be controlled via a Django channels websockets. The python script runs a physical motor, so some example functions would be Start() and Stop().

Edit: Looks like what I want is to setup celery to control the python script, but have django channels control the celery application on when t to start and stop:https://vincenttide.com/blog/1/django-channels-and-celery-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can write a websocket client in python that connects to your server. There a many ways to do this. For example you can use the libary [websocket](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html)

An example code could look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import asyncio
import websockets

ws_url = "ws://domain_of_your_server:8000/ws/"

async def command_receiver():
    async with websockets.connect(ws_url) as websocket:
        while True:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            await websocket.send("Received the command '{message}'")
            if message == "start":
                # run the start command
                ...
            elif message == "stop":
                # run the stop command
                ...
            else:
                await websocket.send("Unknown command")     


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(command_receiver())
```